# SQL Syntax issue (left join)

Tags: sql, syntax, left-join

So I'm having a problem with a query, and I don't really understand where. A comment is placed where the syntax error is. The query is much larger, I tried to shorten it to make a valid but tidier query.

This is using odbc to connect to a Progress database. I'm told it uses strict SQL-92.

```
SELECT itemcust."item-cust", 
       itemcust."cust-no", 
       corptreeCust.code 

FROM      pub."item-cust" itemcust 
JOIN      pub.customer cust 
left join pub.salesstructcustomer struct 
     on ( struct."corp-cust-type" = cust."corp-cust-type" 
      and struct."corp-cust-num" = cust."corp-cust-num" 
     ) 
left join pub.corptree corptreeCust 
      on ( corptreeCust.uid = struct.corptreeid /* program says SQL Syntax error here */
       and corptreeCust.category = 'store' 
      ) 

where ( itemcust."in-entity" = {$entity} or itemcust."in-entity" = '*') 
  and itemcust."item-no" = {$itemno} 
  and ( itemcust."cust-no" = {$custno} or itemcust."cust-no" = '*') 
  and cust."cust-no" = {$custno}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I should note that the `structc` is an artifact leftover from the fact that it's a larger query. Essentially there are six total left joins, one to get `structa`, and get the corp-cust record that corresponds to it, and the same for `structb` and `structc`.

Comment: Where's the ON criteria for the CUSTOMER table?

Comment: And if you still feel the need to do this, remember that you need to evaluate your new version not only for correctness (does it return exactly the same rows as the old one) but for performance. Often the query that looks awful to you is a far better performer and messing with it when it isn't broken can lead to unfortunate losses of performance for no gain to the users just to potentially make maintaining it take five or ten minutes less.

Comment: @HLGEM I did not have a valid working query - I was tidying it up for purposes of posting it here rather than make a giant query that displays far more than required to illustrate the problem (which OMG Ponies pointed out.) The only reason to tidy it was to put it on SO. And... ugly queries in the code are the least of the concerns when you consider the unfortunate background of this project.

Comment: @Ponies, Kevin - I had thought that would be handled in the WHERE clause. I'm going to fix that, because even if that isn't the issue, it needs to be, and like Kevin said it could be messing up the parser.

Comment: @glowcoder, it is usually a bd practice to mix implict (using the where clause) and explicit joins when you have left joins. Databases can interpet them incorrectly and cause problems. And ther is no reason to ever use an implicit join in new code.

Comment: @glowcoder Apparently I misread what you said and apolgise for my earlier comment. I'm deleting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I appreciate the responses. The fact that there was no ON clause was a serious issue, but it actually wasn't the real problem.

The problem actually was that `uid` is a reserved word, and I had to make it `corptreeCust.\"uid\"`

=(

Answer (score 6):

Your table alias for `pub.salesstructcustomer` is `struct`, not `structc` as referenced in the join.

Answer (score 5):

Is that a typo? Looks like it's looking at structc instead of struct, unless I missed something.

Answer (score 3):

You don't seem to have an on clause between cust and itemcust. That could certainly be confusing the parser into throwing an error further down the query